# iframe/embed vid in text widget loads outside container and moves around when scrolling the page?

Tags: widgets, videos, embed

I've inherited webmaster tasks for a site re-design that involves heavy use of widgets.

On the frontpage, two videos are loading in two text widgets, and they play fine once loaded. The problem is that on first load of the page, the video that uses `<embed />` loads randomly up by the top left hand corner of the screen and then jumps down the page to its container  - once the page is cached it stays within its container.

The second iframe video loads within its container, but then moves around slightly when you scroll up and down the page.

This issue just began yesterday which is weird because all development has stopped this week and they've been fine before. It is most noticeable in IE9, although I've been able to recreate it randomly in Firefox on Windows and Mac. Haven't tried IE8/7.

There are videos loading in text widgets in the sidebar on the other pages in the site (mostly iframes), and there are no problems on any of those pages.

www.redrockla.com/roomag/

Thank you for any suggestions, and please let me know if you need code in a pastebin.

(Also, I didn't develop the site myself, so if there are any other fixable errors you see that I may not know about, please feel free to let me know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Chrome, IE9 and IE8 all without a problem and even on a slow Starbucks connection. But it might help to give height and width attributes to all the images above to prevent the page from cascading.

The second problem (i.e. the object jumping during scroll) I think is simply an IE rendering flaw - not really a bug. It just doesn't handle it well, and you can notice it even on YouTube.

Comment: thanks for checking developdaly, and good tip about adding the size attributes.